# throw a cross-browser syntax error with fileName and lineNumber in javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'am developing a code-parser and now I would throw a syntax error with a specific filename and line number. I have tried:

```
new SyntaxError(message, fileName, lineNumber)
```

it works fine in Firefox, but the Chrome developer tools don't show the correct file or the line number. 
I searched a lot, but I can't find anything about it. Is there a crossbrowser solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError#Browser_compatibility

states it works in all modern browsers. howerver you forgot `throw`:

```
try {
     var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
     var lastScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
     var scriptName = lastScript.src;

     throw new SyntaxError("Hello", scriptName, 10);
} catch (e) {
     console.log(e instanceof SyntaxError); // true
     console.log(e.message); // "Hello"
     console.log(e.name); // "SyntaxError"
     console.log(e.fileName); // "someFile.js"
     console.log(e.lineNumber); // 10
     console.log(e.columnNumber); // 0
     console.log(e.stack); // "@Scratchpad/2:11:9\n"
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7xs488mf/

Comment: sorry, I don't forgot to throw, I forgot to write it in the post. The problem is not the SyntaxError Object it is the fileName property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/fileName#Browser_compatibility I get an error but it does not refer to the file (in chrome).

Comment: @jan I think it really is a chrome limitation try the fiddle